# how can i get customer id list on onepagecontroller page?

Tags: magento

Hello when a user place a order,i want to update a custom field of all customer.Though i have created custom field in customer section.
For this i am using following code.but by this code i am unable to find customer ids.
Please tell me how can i find customer ids in loop.

```
$productId='1';
$order= Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id',$productId);
foreach ($order_collection as $itemId => $item)
 {
   $customerid=$item->getCustomerId();
 }
```

Comment: $orderId=$item->getOrderId(); by this i can get order id here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')` won't have customer Id's see the database table: `sales_flat_order_item` You'll want to use `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` to retrieve such from `sales_flat_order`